# Custom query with Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: castle-activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to execute a custom query with Castle ActiveRecord.

I was able to run simple query that returns my entity, but what I really need is the query like that below (with custom field set):

*select count(1) as cnt, data from workstationevent where serverdatetime >= :minDate and serverdatetime < :maxDate and userId = 1 group by data having count(1) > :threshold*

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case what you want is `HqlBasedQuery`. Your query will be a projection, so what you'll get back will be an `ArrayList` of tuples containing the results (the content of each element of the ArrayList will depend on the query, but for more than one value will be `object[]`).

```
HqlBasedQuery query = new HqlBasedQuery(typeof(WorkStationEvent),
    "select count(1) as cnt, data from workstationevent where 
     serverdatetime >= :minDate and serverdatetime < :maxDate 
     and userId = 1 group by data having count(1) > :threshold");

var results = 
    (ArrayList)ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query);
foreach(object[] tuple in results)
{
    int count = (int)tuple[0]; // = cnt
    string data = (string)tuple[1]; // = data (assuming this is a string)

    // do something here with these results
}
```

You can create an anonymous type to hold the results in a more meaningful fashion. For example:

```
var results = from summary in 
    (ArrayList)ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query)
    select new {
        Count = (int)summary[0], Data = (string)summary[1]
    };
```

Now results will contain a collection of anonymous types with properties `Count` and `Data`. Or indeed you could create your own summary type and populate it out this way too.

ActiveRecord also has the `ProjectionQuery` which does much the same thing but can only return actual mapped properties rather than aggregates or functions as you can with HQL.

Comment: I've seen Ayende do something like this.  I'll also have to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware though, if you're using ActiveRecord 1.0.3 (RC3) as I was, this will result in a runtime InvalidCastException. ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery returns an ArrayList and not a generic ICollection. So in order to make it work, just change this line:

```
var results = (ICollection<object[]>) ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

to

```
var results = (ArrayList) ActiveRecordMediator.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

and it should work.

Also note that using count(1) in your hql statement will make the query return an ArrayList of String instead of an ArrayList of object[] (which is what you get when using count(*).)

Just thought I'd point this out for the sake of having it all documented in one place.